# Thin boots instead of puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, websocket, puma

I'm trying to make a chat application deployed on a puma ec2 instance and have puma gem declared on my gemfile, but rails-websockets gem requires thin. For some reason when I start my server it uses thin instead of puma.

How to force my app to boot puma instead of thin?

I'm having issues since I cannot start a thread for web sockets, so I'm getting 500 error trying to access /websockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue chatting on the IRC with the gem developer that requires thin.

He gave me a alternative branch that its not used and Puma started to work normally.

Also, for my websocket problem, I used [this guide](https://chrislea.com/2013/02/23/proxying-websockets-with-nginx/) to understand how my nginx works. So I entered these lines on my ec2 instance nginx config file:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

so my conection could be updradable.